# XMPP Proxy Server with Tinder/Whack

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, whack

I'm looking to create a proxy server for XMPP that does the absolute bare minimum: allow a client to successfully connect to it (handshaking).  After that, I'd like to trap the stanzas sent to it and perform pass-throughs which will route the stanzas to the actual XMPP service, which will be OpenFire.

But I need that initial proxy first to represent 'connected' clients.I was considering using Tinder and Whack.  Will those libraries contain the functionality I need or do I need to start from scratch?

I will be using Java.

Please don't recommend a light-weight XMPP server for my needs, this has to be done in the way outlined above, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if the [ConnectionManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/connection_manager.jsp) suits your needs.

As for doing it yourself, Tinder would probably be helpful, but I don't think Whack is of any use, since you are not building a component.